# Emacs php-mode and paredit

Tags: php, emacs, php-mode, paredit

I would like to use paredit in combination with php-mode, but it doesn't add a closing curly bracket "}". Might this have something todo with the fact that an electric brace is bound to "{"? And how could I overwrite this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using paredit is php-mode is a bad idea - it's mostly suited for Lisp code editing. There is a very nice alternative for general purpose development though - [autopair-mode](http://code.google.com/p/autopair/). It's very easy to use and inserts braces, brackets and quotes in a manner similar to the one present in most IDEs.

Comment: I found `autopair-mode` horrendously slow when I had a large number of open buffers. `paredit-mode`, on the other hand, always feels snappy, which is why I use it everywhere.

Comment: Emacs 24 contains a new global `electric-pair-mode`, which might be faster?

Comment: Yep, it is. I've moved on from `autopair-mode` to the new `electric-pair-mode`. It's slightly less capable, but a lot faster indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Some time ago, I wrote such a thing for C, but you can easily use it for PHP as well:

```
(define-minor-mode c-helpers-minor-mode
  "This mode contains little helpers for C developement"
  nil
  ""
  '(((kbd "{") . insert-c-block-parentheses))
)

(defun insert-c-block-parentheses ()
  (interactive)
  (insert "{")
  (newline)
  (newline)
  (insert "}")
  (indent-for-tab-command)
  (previous-line)
  (indent-for-tab-command)
  )

(add-hook 'php-mode-hook 'c-helpers-minor-mode)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, `autopair-mode` felt extremely sluggish when a large number of buffers were open (plus, `paredit-mode` ensures that delimiters are *never* unbalanced, unlike `autopair-mode`). So if, like me, you absolutely want to use `paredit-mode` and nothing else will do, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8602965/504611). In the elisp snippet given there, just replace `slime-repl-mode-map` and `slime-repl-mode-hook` with the corresponding variables for php (most likely `php-mode-map` and `php-mode-hook`)